# textract job failed for pdf file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am unable to process a pdf file stored in s3 bucket. I am using below code repository.

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-code-samples/blob/master/python/12-pdf-text.py

Error details:

Started job with id 43950fhihfe0r94th34hf0934hf349hg034fh9304fj90349gh349f
Job status is FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/hima459004/PycharmProjects/testproject/textract.py", line 62, in 
for item in resultPage['Blocks']:
KeyError: 'Blocks'
Result set page received 1

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check before accessing Blocks key in resultPage json/dict variable

```
for resultPage in response:
    if 'Blocks' in resultPage.keys():
        for item in resultPage["Blocks"]:
            if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
                print ('\033[94m' +  item["Text"] + '\033[0m')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It worked.